# CSS float LI with varying heights without gap

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float a list into 2 columns. Each `li` has a different height and I'm trying to make this happen without giant spacing gaps.

This is as close as i have gotten:

http://jsfiddle.net/kR94q/1/

**HTML**

NOTE: I dont have `br` tags like this, just did it to make each height different. It represents content.

```
<ul>
    <li><br /><br /><br /></li>
    <li><br /><br /></li>
    <li><br /><br /><br /><br /></li>
    <li><br /></li>
    <li><br /><br /><br /></li>
    <li><br /><br /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; list-style: none; padding: 0; }
ul li { width: 138px; margin: 1px 5px; border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; background-color: blue; float: left;}
ul li:nth-child(2n+1) { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of just using two `<ul>` elements (I imagine that you're constrained by however the html is currently being rendered), You could try out the `column-count` property (css3) for a quick fix!

```
ul { 
    /* your existing css */
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
}
```

Also, I removed the float property `:nth-child(2n+1)` property to keep the columns lined up while approaching it this way.

Forked your fiddle here: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/2AhQy/1/)**

Comment: @Cameron Hurd There are still some issues with your Fiddle. Using `columns` and floating the child elements doesn't make sense. I made an updated Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/kR94q/8/**.

Answer (score 1):

May be using flex display ?

```
ul { width: 300px; 
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; list-style: none; padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kR94q/5/)

Comment: Flexbox doesn't seem to be the right choice in this case. Mainly for two reasons. Firstly it will stretch a lower box or fill the space (below). And secondly Firefox still does not support flex-wrap.