# Multiple columns of links allowing for multiple lines

Tags: html, css, list

I am currently trying to create a 2 column list of links, however when a link goes onto multiple lines, it leaves a gap in the next column. I have solved similar problems in the past using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), though this always seems overkill everytime I need to use it. Is there a clean CSS way of achieving this layout without using JQuery plugins and the like?

[image: Multiple columns]

**Markup**

```
<ul class="two-col-links">
    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Press</a></li>
    <li><a href="">NMMT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Partners &amp; <br>Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Terms &amp; <br>Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evx350nb/)

Note on the example above how "Partners & links" leaves a gap on the left hand column - is there a way around this to remove this gap?

Comment: Not really unless you're willing to change your markup, like this (and don't quote me on semantics) http://jsfiddle.net/evx350nb/

Comment: @Chad No difference..?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't copy for some reason. http://jsfiddle.net/evx350nb/1/

Comment: If I have to make that structure my html would always be: http://jsfiddle.net/evx350nb/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS float LI with varying heights without gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801135/css-float-li-with-varying-heights-without-gap)

Comment: There's currently no pure css solution with great support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `float` is a bad idea. Try to use `column-count` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Look example:

```css
ul {
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="two-col-links">
 <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Press</a></li>
 <li><a href="">NMMT</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Sitemap</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Partners &amp; <br>Links</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Terms &amp; <br>Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @wickywills Use column-width on the ul rather than width on the li.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Note that this will cause the options to flow downwards rather than left-to-right, and does not work on Internet Explorer earlier than version 10.  If those constraints are acceptable to you, this is the most robust approach since it can be extended to multiple columns if the number of options in your menu increases.

Comment: Had to accept other answer, as they were a couple of mins faster, but +1'd for the effort :) Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I upvoted @tutankhamun's answer for the same reason.